# How to popup a picker view in tableview row when I click the row label view. After clicking the done button, hide the picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, uipicker

Now I have a table view. It have several rows. In one row, when I click on it, it should popup a picker view from bottom. After choosing, clicking the done button, it would be hidden. And value I picked in the picker should be passed to the row view.

All values in the picker was designed in a NSArray defined in .m file.

Comment: use `didSelectAtRow` method for tableview and check for particular index using `indexpath.row` and if it is desired index then pop up show `pickerview` and hide it when click on `done`

Comment: I only know using another view controller to control the pickerView. And all can be done through it.

Comment: thx Mohit, I have used this method to pass value to the label. But it is in another view controller, not in the same one.

Comment: then push to that view controller and on done pop it back

Comment: What I want is in the same controller, not two controllers. In one controller, click the view, picker popup, choose the value, click the done button, it is hidden, value is shown on the view.

Comment: you can do that same as i told you in my first comment. you can do this with the help of that solution

Comment: If I do so, how to design the storyboard? How to response the picker/

Comment: add the picker over tableview, make it hidden on initial stage and show it when desired row selected. make it hidden again when done clicked

Comment: Yeah, I know this way. What I confused is if I drag a Picker View into the table, it takes a lot of space. If it is hidden, the blank would still be there. If I make a view at the bottom of the table view. It still has blank when it is hidden.

Comment: did you set any background color?

Comment: It is default color. Should I put it at the bottom of the table view?